# Ionic apps not having crisp and sharp images

Tags: html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have seen ionic apps and the way I see the UI, they are not having that crisp and sharp images that the native apps can offer. Icons are kind of pixelated and the colors are not that vibrant.

I'm not sure if that is a limitation of HTML5 apps. Is there a way we can address this issue?

Comment: is it only with iOS retina devices or just any?

Comment: Hmmm im not sure with that. Maybe somebody here can confirm?

Comment: for retina screens this can help http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2012/creating-retina-images-for-your-website/